# Google analytics issue or limitation

Tags: php, html, google-analytics

I want request count of each request on the server.
My URL can be www.domain.com?module=development_dashboard&action=login.

Google analytics work fine in this case.

But my issue is "If I call a module's action using ajax and It returns data in the format on JSON". I guess in such case Google analytics will not able to track that request.

Is there any alliterate way to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Google's Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#SettingUpEventTracking) to track whenever your ajax call fires its success call back.

```
success: function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'subcategory', 'details']);
}
```

Comment: will it work in case of ajax requests where server return me data in JSON format.

Comment: What you probably want to do it check to see if the JSON you get back is correct, or what you expected, and if everything is okay and you are about to alter the DOM to add in your new content, then call the _gaq.push() and it will track that event.

Comment: Ok got it but we have large system having thousands of pages. It is very difficult to search Ajax calls and inject above code on each of them.

Comment: Perhaps you could look into [.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/).

Another option would be server side watching for ajax requests,and inject a call to the _gaq.push method in your returning ajax data (which goes and can be executed on the client). I'm not sure if Google Analytics has a PHP API, but you could look into this as well, instead of having to send data/function call back to the client as JS.